# Main site single-property.php design, as homepage of a multisite

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, multisite, query-posts

I've been researching how to do this for some time now, and I'm coming up short.

I have my main blog, example.com, which we've created a custom post type of Property. I'm needing the exact layout and format of a single-property (example.com/blog/property/1exampleproperty) to be the homepage, when we create other sites through multisite. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Will all the sites be using a common theme?

Comment: Yes all sites using the same theme. Preferably at least.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options; either bake into the theme (functions.php) or write a simple plugin that auto-creates the post based on hooking into after new site (blog) creation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wpmu_new_blog

Use the insert post function to do the creation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Then, set as the home page based on ID returned:

```
update_option( 'page_on_front', $new_page->ID );
```